# iPhone - core data NSSet relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have two entities Books and Bundles. A book can belong to none, to one or more bundles. So I have a bi-directional to-many relationship between these entities.

I am about to setup the value of this relationship on the Book part.

If the attribute was a regular one, I would simply do something like

```
aBook.title = @"this is my title";
```

If I wanted to set the title for a book. But as this is a bi-directional to-many relationship, core data says it is a NSSet attribute.

My question is: how do I set and read values from this attribute?

I first thought it was a regular NSSet. So, after reading the product I simple did

```
NSSet *aSet = Book.fromBundle;
```

but for my dismay aSet contained zero objects

So I thought I was setting it in error.
I set it earlier doing

```
Book.fromBundle = [NSSet setWithObject:aBundle];
```

(yes, all changes were saved to the database)

am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a normal set, but core data advises against directly assigning a new set (for this very reason). If you are using a custom class, the standard implementation would include `addFromBundleObject:` and `removeFromBundleObject:` methods for you to use. If you do not use a custom class, or choose not to implement these methods, then you can use the `mutableSetValueForKey:` method to get a set which you can modify.

```
NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [book mutableSetValueForKey:@"fromBundle"];
[mutableSet addObject:aBundle];
```

Comment: thanks. The app is not crashing anymore, but after using this command several times to add different bundles to a book, the book just stores the last one. I have inspected the database in an external app because I have not figured out yet how to create a predicate on the request to check and see if the bundle object is on fromBundle. On a too-many relationship I would use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(fromBundle ==%@)", aBundle], but I have no clue how to do that on a NSSet... if you can help with that too, I appreciate (if it is not to ask too much) ... :D

Comment: One-to-many relationships are basically the same as many-to-many relationships. Both are represented as NSSets. The only difference is how the inverse relationship is set. You should be able to do the same thing you would for one-to-many relationship.